# How to find 'non-unique' value from array when using 'unique' in perl

Tags: string, perl, unique

```
my @words = qw(1 2 3 4 4);
my @unique_words = uniq @words;

print @unique_words; # 1 2 3 4
```

I am interested in finding which value was non-unique, in this case `4`. And being able to set it equal to a variable so that I can keep track of which specific value  was re-occuring.

I want to do this so I can implement a code that says "if my string contains *duplicating value from array* completely remove *duplicating value from array* from string". In this case, if a string contained `1 2 3 4 4`. I would like it after the if statement to contain `1 2 3`.

Comment: @toolic Thanks for the response! How do I print the value that was counted more than once with this implementation of code?

Answer (score 2):

Counting/finding duplicates is easiest done with a hash:

```
my %count;
$count{ $_ }++ for @words;
print "$_ occurs more than once\n"
    for grep { $count{ $_ } > 1 } @words;
```

Finding the values that only occur once is done by looking for the elements in `%count` that have a count of 1:

```
my %count;
$count{ $_ }++ for @words;
my @unique_words = grep { $count{ $_ } == 1 } @words;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Is there anyway that I can set $_, equal to a variable that holds the value that occurs more than once? So that I may be able to do comparisons globally in my program? Thank you very much for your guidance in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the value that occurs more than once"? There can be more than one value that occurs more than once. The expression `grep { $count{ $_ } > 1 } keys %count;` returns all the values that occur more than once. You can hold on that list by using `my @duplicates = grep { $count{ $_ } > 1 } keys %count;` .

Comment: or make the list of only non-duplicated values with `my @non_duplicates = grep { $count{$_} == 1 } @words;`

Comment: @ysth Thank you so much. That helped a lot. I think that was what I've been looking for.

Comment: @Corion Thank you, that helped a lot.